# what is the Open Cloud Computing Interface?

Tags: web-services, interface, cloud

I am going to develop a cloud application and in my research for state of the art tools in Cloud Computing i saw some references to OCCI (Open Cloud Computing Interface).

I was not able to find out an answer to the following questions

1)*Is it easy to use this Interface ?*

2)*What programming languages does this interface Supports ?*

3)*Is this Interface mature enough?*

Any information are well appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked quite some time ago but, hopefully, the answer is still relevant.

1. Is it easy to use?

   Depends on what you want. If you want to make your own implementation, then probably not. If you use one of the existing implementations (see bellow), then **yes**.
2. What programming languages does this interface Support?

   We know about two implementations (libraries, CLI), which are for **Ruby** and **Java**. See:

   - https://wiki.egi.eu/wiki/rOCCI:ROCCI
   - https://github.com/EGI-FCTF/jOCCI-api

   rOCCI (the first one) also as a server side (the rOCCI-server) that translates OCCI to propriatary cloud management platforms such as OpenNebula.
3. Is this Interface mature enough?

   **Yes**, given that it is being used by real-world infrastructures. Among them, e.g., the [EGI Federated Cloud](http://www.egi.eu/infrastructure/cloud/). That said, the current OCCI specification (1.1) has a few shortcomings that will be addressed in version 1.2 (due in Autumn 2015), so that if someone is just starting a project, it is worth implementing with 1.2 already.

Answer (score 0):

Many of your questions can be answered (positively, by the way!) by visiting the OCCI-WG home site at http://occi-wg.org and/or searching on "occi implementation".

Another recent and useful resource is the tutorials and workshop talks given at the recent Cloud Interoperability Week held simultaneously with events in Madrid and Santa Clara, part of the Cloud Plugfest hands-on developer training series:

Or generally at http://www.cloudplugfest.org/

The basic specs are published by the Open Grid Forum.

Comment: Thank you for your answer dear Alan .I would like to tell you that i visited the website but the reason that i asked inside the forum is because i would like the opinion from people that used it and have experience on it. We shouldn't think Stack overflow only as a place to give absolute answers to questions with yes and no . I consider the site as a place to have productive discussion that we can all benefit from . Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

The Open Cloud Computing Interface (OCCI) is a set of specifications delivered through the Open Grid Forum, for cloud computing service providers. OCCI has a set of implementations that act as proofs of concept. It builds upon World Wide Web fundamentals by using the Representational State Transfer (REST) approach for interacting with services.